# Epson fx 890 dot matrix printer custom page size

Tags: printing

I installed Epson fx 890 dot matrix printer on Ubuntu 14.04. But i'm having a problem setting it up to print in a custom paper size. I have turned "page auto tear" to off, but it is not working properly.

What happens when I try to print is, that the print completes in middle of the pages, instead of printing the full page.

Comment: According to http://www.openprinting.org/printer/Epson/Epson-FX-890 this printer does NOT work with Linux!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Changing the Default-setting mode in the printer worked for me. You can follow the instructions here: http://files.support.epson.com/pdf/fx890_/fx890_u1.pdf

1. Make sure the printer is on and paper is loaded. Then press the
   Menu buttons (ItemU and Set) until the printer beeps and both the
   Tear Off/Bin lights turn on.
   The printer enters default-setting mode and prints a line showing
   which language is currently selected for printing the instructions.
   The selected language is underlined.
2. If you want a different language, press the ItemD button until the
   printout shows the language you want underlined.
3. Press the Set button to accept the language. The printer prints a line
   asking if you want to print all the current settings.
4. To print a list of all the current settings, press the Set button. The
   printer prints all the settings and then the first setting again. Go to
   step 5.
   To go through the settings one at a time, press the ItemD or ItemU
   button. The printer prints the first setting and its current value.
5. Press the Set button to scroll through the options for the selected
   setting until you see the one you want.
   Press the ItemD or ItemU button to select the next or previous
   setting you want to change.
6. Repeat step 5 for any other settings you want to change.
7. When you finish, press the Menu buttons again to exit
   default-setting mode.
   Your new settings become the printer’s defaults

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.